# NSFetchedResultsController – getting exception when a new section is created (UPDATE: might be when all rows in a section is deleted...)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsoperation

I've got a view with a TableView and an NSFetchedResultsController.
I'm using a ASINetworkQueue (subclass of NSOperationQueue) and a subclass of ASIHTTPRequest (which in turn is a subclass of NSOperation) to download a JSON feed, parse it and insert corresponding entities into Core Data.
Therefore, in the ASIHTTPRequest subclass, I've got a second NSManagedObjectContext to keep everything threadsafe and nice.

Everything is fine, my background fetching/import fires of each 10 seconds or so, new entities are created and saved into the Core Data store. The NSNotification propagates its way to the ViewController and the NSFetchedResultsController and new rows appear in the TableView.

The problem occurs when the JSON contains an entity with a new value of the section key (lets call it "sectionID") – for example sectionID == 2 instead of sectionID == 1 (you get it?).

At this point, the NSFetchedResultsController should make the table view create a new section, but instead I'm getting an exception:

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[NSArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0] with userInfo (null)
Assertion failed: (_Unwind_SjLj_Resume() can't return), function _Unwind_SjLj_Resume, file /SourceCache/libunwind/libunwind-24.1/src/Unwind-sjlj.c, line 326.
```

Here is my code for the NSFetchedResultControllers delegate methods:

```
-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{

    [[self eventTable] beginUpdates];

}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    NSIndexSet* set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex];
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [[self eventTable] insertSections:set withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [[self eventTable] deleteSections:set withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView* tv = [self eventTable];
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self tableView:tv configureCell:[tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
    }
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [[self eventTable] endUpdates];
}
```

Any thoughts about whats causing the exception? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 2011-02-03**
Not really sure whether the error occurs when a new section is created, or an old one is deleted. I almost think that this occurs when all the rows in a section is deleted, but by some reason the controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType is not being called.
Anyone with experience of something similar?

**UPDATE 2011-02-08**
I think I solved it. The problem was that some extra conditions had to be taken into concern when determining whether to delete the row/section or not.
When using the code supplied in the Apple documentation (along with a few adjustments to make it work in my view), it runs OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved it. The problem was that some extra conditions had to be taken into concern when determining whether to delete the row/section or not. When using the code supplied in the Apple documentation (along with a few adjustments to make it work in my view), it runs OK.

**UPDATE 2011-03-22**

Basically I used the same approach as in [SafeFetchedResultsController](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2010/02/more-bugs-in-nsfetchedresultscontroller.html).

Comment: Might be a good idea to explain what you did and solved your problem.

Comment: Added comment and link above.

Comment: The File isnt it in the link. Can someone share it or give another link with SafeFetchedResultsController?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the reason for your error but you are missing the NSFetchedResultsChangeMove case in your delegate methods.

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
    [changedTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [changedTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But do I need it even if objects can't be moved? New ones can only be inserted and old ones get deleted (according to the JSON import in the background), but the user can't reorder the rows.